# Keras BayesianOptimization tuner makes the "best val_loss" worse during tuning

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, keras-tuner

I'm tuning a model with the Keras tuner `BayesianOptimization`. The tuning objective is `val_loss` which is calculated after each epoch. As I understand it, the tuner will go through various hyperparameter configurations and train the model while keeping track of `val_loss`. It saves the model weights of the model at the epoch with the lowest (best) `val_loss`. After tuning, the tuner method `get_best_models` returns the model that had the best `val_loss` at any point in its training.

However, looking at the tuning log, I've noticed that the final supposed best `val_loss` isn't actually the lowest `val_loss` it reported during tuning. In the log you can see how the "best so far" `val_loss` increases to 0.431 after trial 64 which had a much worse `val_loss`.

Here's an excerpt of the log: (I've omitted log lines from training with `...`)

```
Search: Running Trial #62

Hyperparameter    |Value             |Best Value So Far 
lstm_reg          |0.01              |0                 
lstm_units        |384               |416               
learning_rate     |0.01741           |0.00062759        

Epoch 1/200
58/58 - 8s - loss: 5.8378 - mean_absolute_error: 0.8131 - val_loss: 2.1253 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.6561
...
Epoch 26/200
58/58 - 5s - loss: 0.4074 - mean_absolute_error: 0.4579 - val_loss: 0.8352 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.5948
Trial 62 Complete [00h 02m 37s]
val_loss: 0.5230200886726379

Best val_loss So Far: 0.396116703748703
Total elapsed time: 04h 32m 29s

Search: Running Trial #63

Hyperparameter    |Value             |Best Value So Far 
lstm_reg          |0.001             |0                 
lstm_units        |288               |416               
learning_rate     |0.00073415        |0.00062759        

Epoch 1/200
58/58 - 5s - loss: 0.8142 - mean_absolute_error: 0.6041 - val_loss: 0.8935 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.5796
...
Epoch 45/200
58/58 - 5s - loss: 0.1761 - mean_absolute_error: 0.2561 - val_loss: 0.8256 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.6804
Trial 63 Complete [00h 04m 04s]
val_loss: 0.527589738368988

Best val_loss So Far: 0.396116703748703
Total elapsed time: 04h 36m 34s

Search: Running Trial #64

Hyperparameter    |Value             |Best Value So Far 
lstm_reg          |0.01              |0                 
lstm_units        |384               |416               
learning_rate     |0.00011261        |0.00062759        

Epoch 1/200
58/58 - 6s - loss: 4.1151 - mean_absolute_error: 0.6866 - val_loss: 3.3185 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.4880
...
Epoch 94/200
58/58 - 6s - loss: 0.3712 - mean_absolute_error: 0.3964 - val_loss: 0.7933 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.5781
Trial 64 Complete [00h 09m 06s]
val_loss: 0.6574578285217285

Best val_loss So Far: 0.43126755952835083
Total elapsed time: 04h 45m 40s

Search: Running Trial #65

Hyperparameter    |Value             |Best Value So Far 
lstm_reg          |0.0001            |0                 
lstm_units        |480               |256               
learning_rate     |0.010597          |0.05              

Epoch 1/200
58/58 - 6s - loss: 1.1511 - mean_absolute_error: 0.7090 - val_loss: 1.1972 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.6724
...
```

The tuning summary states the best `val_loss` is 0.400 even though it must have found a model at some point with `val_loss` at 0.396 which is actually better. (in trial 58 to be exact)

```
Best val_loss So Far: 0.4001617431640625
Total elapsed time: 15h 06m 02s
Hyperparameter search complete. Optimal parameters: ...
```

This is the code that creates the tuner:

```py
tuner = kt.BayesianOptimization(
        feedback_model_builder,
        objective="val_loss",
        directory="./model_tuning",
        project_name=name,
        max_trials=200
    )
```

and starts the tuning process:

```py
tuner.search(
        multi_window.train,
        validation_data=multi_window.val,
        callbacks=[early_stopping],
        verbose=tf_verbosity,
        epochs=200,
    )
```

Why does the "best" model not have the lowest encountered `val_loss`? Am I misunderstanding how the tuner works or is this a bug?

Answer (score 0):

[I reported this](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-tuner/issues/559) to `keras-tuner` and it seems this is in fact a bug but it hasn't been fixed yet. Since the bug apparently only affects printing, it's probably fine to ignore.